# How to animate multiple widgets while scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I need to implement custom animation while scrolling the list of users. See an example

[image]

My current view is composed of next elements:

`SingleChildScrollView` contains `Column` with:

- `Row` of three top elements (each of is a custom widget with basically `Stack` of avatar, medal and details (`Column`))
- `Row` as a table header
- `ListView` of other users.

`SingleChildScrollView` is wrapped with `NotificationListener` for `ScrollNotification` which is populated to provider. The scroll value is then listened in every top element to perform animation of its own.

I would like to know some general path and algorithm here to take. I tried `AnimatedPositioned` but as soon as it is applied on multiple elements it causes performance issues. Should I use `AnimationController` or some more custom things so far? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: top three avatars and three cards associated with them place inside `CustomMultiChildLayout` and inside the layout delegate pass `ScrollController` as [relayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate/MultiChildLayoutDelegate.html) which will trigger relayout each time the scroll position changes

Comment: alternatively you could switch to slivers and use `SliverPersistentHeader` - the docs say: "A sliver whose size varies when the sliver is scrolled to the edge of the viewport opposite the sliver's GrowthDirection.

In the normal case of a CustomScrollView with no centered sliver, this sliver will vary its size when scrolled to the leading edge of the viewport.

This is the layout primitive that SliverAppBar uses for its shrinking/growing effect."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pskink mentioned, using `SliverPersistentHeader` can be archive, This is a demo widget to illustrate how it can be done. You need to play with value. My favorite part is using `.lerp` , `doubleLerp`... to position the items.

```dart
class Appx extends StatelessWidget {
  const Appx({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned: true,
            delegate: CustomSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 3333,
              width: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate
    extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, constraints) {


      final t = shrinkOffset / maxExtent;
      final width = constraints.maxWidth;
      final itemMaxWidth = width / 4;

      double xFactor = -.4;
      return ColoredBox(
        color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.3),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment:
                  Alignment.lerp(Alignment.center, Alignment(xFactor, -.2), t)!
                    ..x,
              child: buildRow(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple, itemMaxWidth: itemMaxWidth, t: t),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.lerp(
                  Alignment.centerRight, Alignment(xFactor, 0), t)!,
              child:
                  buildRow(color: Colors.red, itemMaxWidth: itemMaxWidth, t: t),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.lerp(
                  Alignment.centerLeft, Alignment(xFactor, .2), t)!,
              child: buildRow(
                  color: Colors.amber, itemMaxWidth: itemMaxWidth, t: t),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Container buildRow(
      {required Color color, required double itemMaxWidth, required double t}) {
    return Container(
      width: lerpDouble(itemMaxWidth, itemMaxWidth * .3, t),
      height: lerpDouble(itemMaxWidth, itemMaxWidth * .3, t),
      color: color,
    );
  }
/// you need to increase when it it not pinned 
  @override
  double get maxExtent => 400;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 300;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: big plus for `lerp`s

Comment: You help me to learn many things, including this lerp, thanks  @pskink

Comment: Thanks a lot @YeasinSheikh ! This brings me the general idea! I need to practice more with Slivers so far, have minimum knowledge about them.